# Find the sum of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} x^{2n-1}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

What is the sum of the following series? $$s(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} x^{2n-1}$$ $$x \in (-1, 1]$$

I would use `Taylor series` for $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n = \frac{1}{1-x}$ but I don't know how to treat the $(-1)^{n+1}$.

So again, what is the sum of $s(x)$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that this is the same as asking for the value of the sum $-\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^nx^{2n-1}$...

Comment: Note:  The Taylor series for ${1\over1-x}$ starts at $n=0$, not $n=1$.

Comment: The series for $x=1$ isn't convergent.

Comment: @abiessu Good point, and then i'm getting $- \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-x^2)^{n+1}$?

Comment: Yes, and see the answers below for how that works out...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}x^{2n-1}=-\frac1x\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-x^2)^n=-\frac1x\frac{-x^2}{1+x^2}=\frac x{1+x^2}$$

Answer (score 4):

What you have is just a geometric series with ratio $-x^2$:

$$s(x)=\sum_{n\ge 1}(-1)^{n+1}x^{2n-1}=\sum_{n\ge 0}(-1)^nx^{2n+1}=x\sum_{n\ge 0}(-x^2)^n=\ldots\;.$$