# Sum of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}(2n-1)x^{2n-1}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

What is the sum of:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}(2n-1)x^{2n-1}, ..|x| \lt 1$$

I need only a final answer as a way to verify my solution, thanks in advance.

EDIT:

my solution:

$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}(-1)^{n+1}(2n-1)x^{2n-1} = $$

$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}(-1)^{n+1}(2n-1)x^{2n-2}x $$

$$x\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}(-1)^{n+1}(2n-1)x^{2n-2} $$

$$ x\int{\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}(-1)^{n+1}(2n-1)x^{2n-2}} = $$

$$x\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}(-1)^{n+1}(2n-1)\frac{x^{2n-1}}{2n-1}  $$

$$x \sum^{\infty}_{n=1}(-1)^{n+1}x^{2n-1} = $$

$$ x \sum^{\infty}_{n=1}(-1)^{n}(-1)x^{2n}x = $$

$$ -x^2 \sum^{\infty}_{n=1}(-1)^{n}x^{2n} = $$

$$ -x^2\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} (-x^2)^n = -x^2 \cdot\frac{-x^2}{1 +x^2} = \frac{x^4}{1+x^2} $$

$$\sum^\infty_{n=1}(-1)^{n+1}(2n-1)x^{2n-1} = (\frac{x^4}{1+x^2})' = \frac{2x^3(x^3+2)}{(x^2)+1)^2}$$

Wrong.

Comment: Can you share your proposed solution?

Comment: @T.Bongers I've solved it about 10 times , and I have only the last solution ..

Comment: @T.Bongers Posted..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}(2n-1)x^{2n-1}=x\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}(2n-1)x^{2n-2}=x\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}x^{2n-1}\right)^{'}$$
and you find the sum $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}x^{2n-1}$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/576391/find-the-sum-of-sum-n-1-infty-1n1-x2n-1/576398#576398).

Answer (score 0):

$$ S:=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}(2n-1)x^{2n-1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n (2n+1)x^{2n+1} $$

Now, consider
$$\begin{align}
S&=x\cdot\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nx^{2n+1}\right) \\
&=x\cdot\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(x\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-x^2)^n\right) \\
&=x\cdot\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(\frac{x}{1+x^2}\right) \\
&=x\frac{(1+x^2)-x(2x)}{(1+x^2)^2} \\
&=\frac{x(1-x^2)}{(1+x^2)^2}
\end{align}$$